# Add liquidity problem

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

I want to list my  token on pancakeswap.
I want add liquidity pool 40.000.000.000.000.000 GNP and 20 bnb
But I can't because when I want to create pool it sends error to me

> Add liquidity failed unknown error ."pancake overflow ". Try increasing your slipage tolerance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply way too many tokens. Assuming your token have 18 decimals, the max amount you can add to a pancake pair would be about 5000000000000000. (that's already 5 quadrillion tokens)

Why would you want to have this many anyways?